# shell command to transform cert file to string with just two \n

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Our parser only accepts certificate strings with two \n...as shown below.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA46ifqDzBpDol+KSQyjjrLWHZ1w2WgEdGB5q8RJqHI7rPkxAc9r9XI71ATxt/KAa156uX3SWxqEYsfxmTQ5AMEwkr0u0iB0B8Ed66M2NPE00DzOyJTpQVTazxvI2hHmuCLXaFz/HL6Kfzz1Q350wW5cY5nnp0/F6bcUlZl3kHDfu7zcSvD/LckWWiO3IgScW69BiBqTVEvUsK/LC/w7F1esqDf8gURuSyZYmg83+OLCPDqwn447YO9001cOtiVAbwCKTwUe89LGB/GtuvNkC8tmdDSP14dAcYPkoJ7418wnbgtUUWVYtt6WRGwfRIDxUnbTRzUjzFY6z4g31JsWZbHQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I am trying to figure out how to use awk or sed to transform the certificate file to a string with only the two \n characters.

Comment: change the parser :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this entirely in `awk`, but I have to run out the door so here is a slightly more hacky solution since I don't have time to think about anything better:

```
echo -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
awk '! /(BEGIN|END) CERTIFICATE/ {print}' ORS='' certificate
echo -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I'm sure someone will come along with something more graceful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `certificate` with your certificate file name.

```
sed '1d;$d' certificate | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/^/-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\\n/' | sed 's/$/\\n-----END PUBLIC KEY---/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/BEGIN[A-Z ][^-]*-----/&\\n/;s/-----END/\\n&/;' certificate
```

Add the `-i` flag to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/BEGIN[A-Z ][^-]*-----/&\\n/;s/-----END/\\n&/;' certificate
```